# Main site is working dreadfully.

Tags: support

I know I posted this before, but I deleted it because I thought the problem was solved. It isn't. The main site and the chatrooms are not working for me. The mainsite loads, but is unusable, in the sense I cannot get any button (inbox, comments, &c) to work and sometimes the site just loads partially. The chatrooms doesn't load, it freezes at the "Loading [name]... just a second." Other sites work perfectly for me, so I am wondering if this is some kind of incompatibility issue with Chrome. It seems not, since I tried using Mozilla and Torch, and the problem persisted.

Can someone help or clarify what the issue is?

(I just changed my gravatar recently, but I think that shouldn't be a problem!)

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of your extensions?  Also, does loading it in incognito give the same results?

Comment: (sorry for the double comment) It could also be a problem with the connection between you and the SE servers.  Try pinging 198.252.206.16 a few times (20 should be good) and see if any of them fail to return.

Comment: If I input that in my bar I see MSEs blue tab but nothing else loads and the tab name is "Site not found..."

Comment: If I enter it not in incognito, I get a page with a Panda saying: "Couldn't find 198.252.206.16. The Q&A site 198.252.206.16 doesn't seem to exist…yet."?

Comment: (How do I ping that? I cannot recall how to open the console on Win7)

Comment: In the start menu, type `cmd` in the text box at the bottom and hit enter.  In the dos prompt, type `ping 198.252.206.16 -n 20` and let it run.

Comment: Ugh, I lost 1 and averaged 186ms. That doesn't sound good.

Comment: From 40 I lost 3 and averaged 166ms.

Comment: 180 ping is reasonable from Argentina to the States, but lost pings could be a sign that the connection is bad.  Try pinging an Argentinian website and see if you get similar results.  The command `ping turismo.gov.ar -n 20` worked for me.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I got $\sim$20ms there, no losses.

Comment: In that case your personal connection is probably fine, so I really don't know what the problem could be.  You could try pinging other US websites (like Google at 173.194.43.5) to see if they show the same ping loss behavior.  I hope whatever it is clears up soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a connection problem. We are currently not experiencing problems on our side. You can get up to date news on our [official status tumblr](http://stackstatus.net/).

In order to verify this try the following steps:

- go to http://speedtest.net and perform a default test. This will measure your local connection speed (typically within a few Km). Note down the values
- perform the same test by choosing a New York server. This is where Stack Overflow is hosted. This test will measure your connection to us.

You should see a decrease in performance, but the values should stay sane. To give you an example, I have a relatively fast connection and get 40Mb/s locally but only around 20Mb/s to New York.